# Rails actions and error message on session expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-timeout

I am using this code for session timeout>

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                                     key: 'your_session_id',
                                     expire_after: 45.minutes
```

It works in the sense that the session variables are set to nil, but I have some code in the sessions#destroy action, which is what happens when a user logs out. I noticed that when the session expires, this action is not executed.

Does anyone know why this is, and how to make it happen? 
Also, how can I make it redirect with a "Session Expired" method to the login page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the expiration of a session doesn't hit any controller action.

If you want to do some redirect if the user session is expired (or otherwise logged out), you could create a `before_action` to handle this. So in your controller file, put this at the top after the class definition:

```
before_action :user_logged_in, only: [#relevant actions which need user login, eg :show ]
```

In a helper method, create the method that the before action will call:

```
def user_logged_in
  unless user_logged_in?
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end
```

And another helper method that returns whether the user is properly logged in or not. (You could combine this with the previous code, but it's often neater to separate so you can use this method elsewhere.)

```
def user_logged_in?
  # some code which tests if the cookie is valid and not expired
end
```

NOTE: For security, it's best not to rely on the cookie expiration time alone. It might make sense in this case, but generally, it's best to store the expiration time on the server and check that in the above method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I already had that, but it just redirects, it doesn't call sessions#destroy action. How can I execute this action in that method?

Comment: Do you mean that after a user's cookie expires you want to redirect them through the sessions#destroy action the next time they load a page?